# Upper div is overlapped by lower div in smaller viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am embedding some dashboard widgets in iframe. I want to make them responsive. So when I reduce screen size, I want each widget to occupy full width and when the browser window is big (`md`+) I want them appear side by side:

```css
iframe {
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid #333 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="myContainer" class="flex-row container-fluid col-xs-12 col-xl-8 pl-0 pr-0 pl-lg-4 pr-lg-4">
  <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 160px;">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pr-1 mt-1 col">
      <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen="" style="display: initial; height: 200%; border: 0px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pl-md-1 mt-1 col">
      <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen="" style="display: initial; height: 200%; border: 0px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that when I reduce browser window, the upper iframe gets overlapped by the lower one:

[image]

How can I fix this?

PS: I am using following:

```
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3"
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
```

Comment: Yes maan this was super quick and super precise!!! It works!!! I wasted several hours on this  !!! But why and how it works??

Comment: I have explained in the answer. Read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code, was that you were giving **height: 200%** to iframe elements. **200%** means that **double of the parent height**. And because of that, it was **overflowing from the parent body**.

One simple fix was to give **height: 100% to iframe element**. So, it takes the **full height of the parent div**.

Here is the updated code:-

```css
    iframe {
      background: pink;
      border: 1px solid #333 !important;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="myContainer" class="flex-row container-fluid col-xs-12 col-xl-8 pl-0 pr-0 pl-lg-4 pr-lg-4">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 160px;">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pr-1 mt-1 col">
        <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen=""
          style="display: initial; height: 100%; border: 0px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pl-md-1 mt-1 col">
        <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen=""
          style="display: initial; height: 100%; border: 0px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Remember that whenever use the percentage, always look the parent element. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot going wrong here. You absolutely should not have a container, a flex row, and a column on the same element.  I suggest a review of the [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) and [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/) docs, then decide which you'll use.

After that, don't mess with the grid by putting padding on containers and rows. They're carefully choreographed elements, and padding really goofs things up. If you want more spacing around your content, add padding to the *column* or margin to the content. If you're trying to remove default column spacing, look at the [gutter docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#gutters).

Note that I removed the 200% height from the iframes. I'm not sure what the intent was there, but generally it's best to let them be their natural height.

`col-12` isn't a thing in Bootstrap 4+, by the way. Just use classes for the breakpoint ranges at which you want to define columns. The element will be full-width by default at smaller screen sizes.

Then, inline styles are a nightmare for all involved. They're hard to fine and interpret at a glance and they require much repetition.  Use the library at your disposal, and use custom CSS classes for the bit of remaining styling you need.

```css
iframe.my-class {
  display: initial;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid #333 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="myContainer" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-1">
      <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen class="my-class"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 mt-1">
      <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen class="my-class"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added `.iframe-container` to create a responsive container for the iframe

```css
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  /*adjust as needed to increase height*/
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.iframe-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px dotted black !important
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>

</style>

<div id="myContainer" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 pr-md-1 mt-1">
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 mt-1">
      <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe src="iframe-link" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```